# How open a link in a PDF in flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, pdf

I am using the PDFx package to display PDFs on flutter application. However, the links embedded in this PDF are not clickable.

How is it possible to make these links clickable an open it in external navigator ?

Comment: can you add the link to the package so people can take a look at it